# Unable to select BlackBerry 9800 as default web simulator on Eclipse

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator

I have some time now working with the BlackBerry's Eclipse Plugin with no issues using the [Curve 8530 Simulator](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477&dl=13D25AAB620AC052D0E4802F4CF8EBBA). Im trying to add the [Torch 9800 Simulator](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477&dl=7280338EEF2D7E6724A5894C3C86370E) but I get this:

[image: Select Default Web Simulator]

Im pretty new on the BB Stuff. 
Im I missing something? 
Is there a debug-enabled version (I check and apparently the version that I have should be pretty capable of debugging)?

Help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** I noticed that I can only add simulators using OS v.5 (e.i BlackBerry Storm2 9550). But the *why* is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking for this issue for over a week, and the only think i can think of  (yet not confirm) is that there are no debugging versions for OS other than 5x.
I was able to debug using all available models for OS5x (Pearl, Tour, Storm, Storm2, Bold, Curve)

So the official answer to this (until some one comes up with a more complete one) is...

There is no support for web debugging on versions other than OS 5x Simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, I have a 4.6.0 simulator here (8220 "T-MobileEU" branded) that is debugging capable, but my 5.0.0 simulator (8530) is not listed as capable. The confusion continues.